# having Key Error while printing json data

Tags: python, json

**python 3.5.1**

hi i have following json and python code and i want to print json data but it has an error that says:

> > Key Error : 'A'

**python**

```
data = json.load(...)
for item in data['x']
    print (item['A'])
```

**json**

```
{"x":[
    {"A":"B"},
    {"C":"D"}
]}
```

whats my problem?

Comment: The second item in `data['x']` will not have a key 'A'. I am not sure what you are trying to do specifically, but if you use `item.get('A')` you will not get a `KeyError`.

Comment: but it doesnt print the first either

Comment: you might be getting the "second" item first. Try it with`.get` and you should get the `"B"`

Comment: You have a single key-value dict. You may use `item.values()`

Comment: `.get` would have 'none' printed and i just want to have one print

Comment: @Scott `if item['A']` will still raise a `KeyError` if that key does not exist. You could use `.get()` and `else: pass` though.

Comment: i wrote this `if item['A'] == none : pass `  `else: print(item['A'])` but it just passes all data without printing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your code assumes that every item in `data['x']` will have a key `'A'`, but as soon as you iterate to a `dict` that does not have such a key you will get a `KeyError`.

Try using `item.get('A')` which will return `None` (or a default you provide) if there is no key `'A'` in your dictionary. It seems like you want to do something like this:

```
data = json.load(...)
for item in data['x']:
    value = item.get('A')
    if value:
        print(value)
    else:
        continue
```

This will print the value associated with the key `'A'` if it exists, otherwise it will move on to the next dictionary in the list.

Answer (score 1):

To print the values in each dictionary (with *unmatching* keys), use the `values` method of the dictionary:

```
data = json.load(...)
for item in data['x']:
    print(item.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

As @elethan pointed the second item would not have key `'A'`

You can do the following

```
data = json.load(...)
for item in data['x']:
    print(item.get('A'))
```

That would not get any error for your specific json input, and print `None` if it won't find `'A'` key in element.

You can also supply default value to `.get()`, e.g. `item.get('A', 'default')`.

Thanks @elethan

Comment: The default for `.get()` is already `None`, so the `None` argument is not necessary AFAIK